# Launching another project from visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This must be simple, but I guess I'm searching with the wrong key words.

I have a visual studio solution(2008) that includes two projects (win32). is it possible for one to launch another? they are entirely self sufficient programs.

Comment: What do you mean with 'launch'?

Comment: Before, during or after compilation?

Comment: @graham.reeds, Not really fussed, but would prefer before or during compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on Project. Select Properties.  Expand Build Events, select Pre-Build Events. In Command Line put the path to your executable.  Use the macro's for this.

If you need one to start before the other then set it to be a dependent of the other. Right click the Solution, select Project Dependencies and choose which project it is dependent on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one project binaray executing the other, yes, this is possible.

If you want Project1 to be executed before or after the compilation of Project 2:

- Set Project2 to be dependent of Project1, so Project1 gets compiled first (Menu Project > Project > Project Dependencies)
- Setup a pre- or post-build-action in Project2 that executes Project1.exe (Project Properties > Build Events > Pre-Build Event or Post-Build Event)

Comment: I would give me also a -1 for the `system`, so I removed it from the answer ;)